# Magento 2 -Display a saved image in a image uploader on page load

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi Guys im using magento 2 image uploader to upload a logo and background for the customer login.
The uploader works fine and saves the image in the media folder .The problem is when I go to the uploader page(admin) ,I would like the saved image from the media folder to be displayed in the image uploader preview .I'm trying to replicate a similar function "changing the frontend header logo" in the contents configuration.

My Ui form

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">upload_form.upload_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">upload_form.upload_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Background Upload</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">upload_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="upload_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\CustomerLogin\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">upload_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="employee_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="imageUploaderExample" formElement="imageUploader">
            <settings>
                <notice translate="true">Some notice.</notice>
                <label translate="true">Image Uploader Example</label>
                <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <imageUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                        <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="string" name="url">myuploads/index/uploadimage</param>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                    </settings>
                </imageUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

Dataprovider.php

```
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName,$reporting,$searchCriteriaBuilder,$request ,$filterBuilder,$meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the saved images in edit page you can use the below code in the `DataProvider` in method `getData` method

```php
/**
* Store manager
*
* @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
*/
private $storeManager;

public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, // add this for getting media url 
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName,$reporting,$searchCriteriaBuilder,$request ,$filterBuilder,$meta, $data);
}

/**
* Get data
*
* @return array
*/
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
        return $this->_loadedData;
    }
    $items = $this->collection->getItems(); // your saved table data's collection model 
    foreach ($items as $item) {

        $data = $item->getData();

        if ($item->getImagePath()) {  // check images saved path from the database.
            $image_temp[0]['name'] = $item->getImagePath();
            $image_temp[0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl().$item->getImagePath();
            $data['image_path'] = $image_temp;
        }

        $this->_loadedData[$item->getId()] = $data;
    }

    return $this->_loadedData;
}


public function getMediaUrl()
{
    $mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()
        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'YOUR_SAVE_DIRECTORY/SUBDIR_TO_APPEND_PATH/';
    return $mediaUrl;
}
```

You can modify this code with your image upload component

`image_path` to `imageUploaderExample` to load the saved images.

Comment: Thank you Viral, but I'm not using any database table, it's an image that's saved in the media folder .i just want to set the name and URL for that UI component.

Comment: In that case you can replace the `$item->getImagePath();` value with your images value of the file that you have kept in the media folder and instead of returning a empty [] array,you can return the images data which you want to display in the pageload. you can simply use : **$this->loadedData['0']['imageUploaderExample'] = $image_temp** and just **return $this->loadedData;**

Comment: I did the above .. it's still not displaying the image.

Comment: there seems to be an issue here $id = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam($this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getRequestFieldName(), null); in the get datasource method ..the $id is null ..is the above datasource config correct?